# Add text to dropdown list of country options billing checkout form

Tags: php, checkout, onepage-checkout, forms, billing-address

I would like to display the shipping costs in my dropdown list of countries (shipping) options. Preferably through a php request, as follows:

[image: shippingcosts]

Guessing I need to add to/or modify this piece in my billing.phtml file:

```
 <div class="field">
       <label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?> </label>

 <div class="input-box">
          <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
 </div>
```

Is there a way to display the shipping costs right after the country value?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you are calculating your shipping cost, if it's a fixed number per country, regardless the weight or other factors, then you can just retrieve that information and in your own module extend **Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract::getCountryHtmlSelect** and there add inside the select option the shipping cost for the current country.